# Entry Query: How to load an entry with the full URL as only criterion

Tags: plugin-development, entry, services, entry-query

From PHP (Plugin), how can I load a certain entry if only the full URL is provided?
I can not find Craft's logic in PHP to split the full URL into the site's baseUrl and the entry's URI.

Please note it's a multisite setup, so my site's baseUrl might look like '`@web/whatever`'

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`UrlManager::_getMatchedElementRoute()`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/UrlManager.php#L378-L413) method does it something like this:

```php
$path = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getPathInfo();
$sitedId = Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->id;

if ($path !== Element::HOMEPAGE_URI) {
    $element = Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementByUri($path, $siteId, true);
}
```

The logic for determining the element can be found in [`Elements::getElementByUri`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/d7874eb87269cf995ed5a72a7ccb5c0851c41b7e/src/services/Elements.php#L838-L886).

I actually cover some of this in the [Bootstrapping the Craft Application](https://putyourlightson.com/reading-crafts-source-code#bootstrapping-the-craft-application) video of the free [Reading Craft's Source Code](https://putyourlightson.com/reading-crafts-source-code) series, which in my biased opinion is well worth a watch.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I already watched part of your series, but somehow lost track of it.